# How to get keys from a Rego table?

Tags: open-policy-agent

Say I have data:

```
> data
{
   "teams": {
      "t1": {
         "count": 1
      },
      "t2": {
          "count": 2
      }
   }
}
```

Input is like:

```
{
   "input": {"team": "t1"}
}
```

I want to have a rule to check if input team exists:

```
team_exists {
  data.teams[_] == input.name # this doesn't work, because data.teams[_] returns team values
}
```

How to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the team is contained in the object like this:

```
data.teams[input.team]
```

In your original example you wrote `data.teams[_] == input.name`. There are two issues with this:

1. When you insert variables (`_` is a unique variable like Go) into references, OPA finds assignments to the variables that make the query true, i.e., it will scan the array/reference/object and find matches. This becomes more obvious if you give the variables names:

```
some key
data.teams[key]
```

In this query OPA would find two results for "key":

```
# Result 1
key = "t1"

# Result 2
key = "t2"
```

2. The RHS should be `input.team` not `input.name`. The latter is missing/undefined. If you had instead written `data.teams[input.name]` (NOTE: incorrect `input` reference) the query would be undefined because `input.name` does not exist.

In general you can perform lookups on objects, arrays, and sets using the same syntax:

```
some_arr := ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
some_arr[1] == "bar"

some_obj := {"foo": "bar", "baz", "qux"}
some_obj["baz"] == "qux"

some_set := {"foo", "bar", "baz"}
some_set["bar"] == "bar" # sets behave like objects where the keys==values
```

See this cheat sheet for other common operations: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-cheatsheet/